# Selenium : Unable to handle Confirmation on a child window in IE Browser

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-iedriver

I am trying to accept/dismiss a confirmation on a child window, my code runs properly on Chrome but fails on IE web driver.

I have a html page [order](https://gist.github.com/bhabanism/40c6a207c95c66ab6ccd4b765d337ba2#file-order-html) which launches a child window [popup](https://gist.github.com/bhabanism/40c6a207c95c66ab6ccd4b765d337ba2#file-popup-html) which displays a confirmation on click of a button

Here's my Java code which runs the selenium - 
[TestConfirmationOnNewWindow.java](https://gist.github.com/bhabanism/40c6a207c95c66ab6ccd4b765d337ba2#file-testconfirmationonnewwindow-java)

I am getting an `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Unable to get browser` exception as below :

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Unable to get browser (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
    Command duration or timeout: 19 milliseconds
    Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
    System info: host: 'BMISHRA2D1', ip: '10.192.38.101', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_101'
    Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
    Capabilities [{browserAttachTimeout=0, enablePersistentHover=true, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, pageLoadStrategy=normal, ie.usePerProcessProxy=false, ignoreZoomSetting=false, handlesAlerts=true, version=11, platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=true, ie.ensureCleanSession=false, elementScrollBehavior=0, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, requireWindowFocus=false, browserName=internet explorer, initialBrowserUrl=http://localhost:36298/, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=false, enableElementCacheCleanup=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss}]
    Session ID: cb1e7828-1760-4fc6-bcee-7e92156d8ef8
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:701)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteTargetLocator.alert(RemoteWebDriver.java:1049)
        at TestConfirmationOnNewWindow.acceptAlert(TestConfirmationOnNewWindow.java:52)
        at TestConfirmationOnNewWindow.testConfirmAlertOnNewWindow(TestConfirmationOnNewWindow.java:38)
        at TestConfirmationOnNewWindow.main(TestConfirmationOnNewWindow.java:28)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

I have tried changing the DesiredCapabilities to ignore just to verify if default dismiss is causing any issue, but still no success.

Link to gist page of the code - https://gist.github.com/bhabanism/40c6a207c95c66ab6ccd4b765d337ba2

I am using IE Web driver version *2.53.1.0 (32 bit)*

Any help/hint on what can be going wrong will help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with newer version of IE Web Driver and this issue is not reproducible.